# Loop through Find and skip when results have only 1 row

Tags: vba, excel

I have done some basic VBA before, but am still very new to the language. This is my first time posting, so I hope I'm posting properly and clearly.

I am currently finding specific criteria in column E of a sheet. My current code works fine but it does not loop, and I only want it to copy the rows if there are 2 or more rows matching that criteria. If there is only 1 row matching, then I would like to skip it.

In my below code, I know that "E04" appears in 2+ rows, so I want to copy those rows to a second sheet named "Misc". However, if my criteria was "E01" which has only 1 row as a result, then I would like to skip this and move on to searching "E02" and so on. The loop I have in my code now is to keep searching for the criteria I named ("E04"), but I dont have a loop to move on to the next criteria.

Here is my current code:

```
Dim FirstAddress As String, _
    cF As Range, _
    RowsToCopy As String

ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 5).Activate
With ActiveSheet.Columns(5)

    Set cF = .Find(What:="E04", _
                After:=ActiveCell, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, _
                SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not cF Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddress = cF.Address
        Do
            cF.EntireRow.Copy
            Sheets("Misc").Range("A" & Sheets("Misc").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Set cF = .FindNext(cF)

        Loop While Not cF Is Nothing And cF.Address <> FirstAddress
   End If
End With
```

Also, here is a bit of what my worksheet looks like...
[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzIzj.png)

You can see that I would like to skip E01-E03, take action on E04, then skip E05-E09, then take action on E10.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated! I have been looking for answers online for hours but haven't found anything that works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use the COUNTIF formula to check how many times the term appears in column E. I'm not sure if you are also asking how to loop. I suggest you substitute an actual sheet name for ActiveSheet as it's more robust.

```
Sub x()

Dim FirstAddress As String, _
    cF As Range, _
    RowsToCopy As String
Dim s As String

s = "EO4"

With ActiveSheet.Columns(5)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, s) > 1 Then
        Set cF = .Find(What:=s, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, _
                    SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not cF Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = cF.Address
            Do
                cF.EntireRow.Copy
                Sheets("Misc").Range("A" & Sheets("Misc").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                Set cF = .FindNext(cF)
            Loop While Not cF Is Nothing And cF.Address <> FirstAddress
        End If
   End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank SJR! That worked perfect for my first concern, I havent used COUNTIF much before so that never even crossed my mind, much appreciated.

Comment: Also, yes I was asking how to LOOP the search criteria. As of now I would need to specifically state E01, then E02, then E03 and so on. Whereas I would like to loop through all those search possibilities, from E01 to E100. Sorry I wasnt very clear on this part of the question.

Comment: Is that a fixed thing, E1 to E100, or does it vary?

Comment: It varies, but I dont think it would go over E100. For example, right now the current sheet goes up to E57, but next time the report may be higher or lower than that.

Comment: What determines the size? Is it a range, the number of sheets ... ?

Comment: It is invoices from a bank. E01 is the first invoice, it can have 1 item or multiple. E02 is the second invoice, it can have multiple items, and so on. So those numbers depend on the amount of transactions processed that day. So I guess the safest bet would be to somehow tell it to search that column for any matches, then take the matches, determine if it is 1 item or multiple (as you already posted above), and then relevant code.

Comment: The most efficient way would be to extract a list of unique values to another sheet (eg using advanced filter) and then loop through that. If you're unsure about how to do that I suggest you post a new question. Perhaps you could also accept this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll look into that. Accepting the answer now, thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks. A pivot table is another option and that would also provide a count of occurrences.